# PyQt and UTF-16 surrogates

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt4, utf-16

Consider the following Python code:

```
In [1]: from PyQt4.QtCore import QTextCodec

In [2]: import codecs

In [3]: surrogate_raw = b'\x34\xd8\x1e\xdd'  # this is UTF-16 encoded character (surrogate pair)

In [4]: QTextCodec.codecForName('utf-16le').toUnicode(surrogate_raw)
Out[4]: '\ud834\udd1e'

In [5]: codecs.getdecoder('utf-16le')(surrogate_raw)
Out[5]: ('', 4)
```

As you can see, string returned from QTextCodec::toUnicode is incorrect. There are two characters with codepoints equal to surrogate values instead of single character. It is not correct unicode (due to reserved codepoints), and this string cannot be translated to another encoding. For example, it is impossible to print string in linux console that uses utf-8:

```
In [6]: incorr = QTextCodec.codecForName('utf-16le').toUnicode(surrogate_raw)

In [7]: print(incorr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-556b71617dae> in <module>()
----> 1 print(incorr)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud834' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Same behavior exists for all QStrings, even ones returned from custom code wrapped by SIP. I had tested this code on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit with Python 3.3.1 and Windows XP 32-bit with Python 3.3.0.

I can guess where this error comes from - in Qt strings are always represented with UTF-16 and you should manually test if QChar is lead or trail surrogate. But Python strings are different, and wrapper does wrong conversion.

In the other hand, PyQt is widely used worldwide for long time and any bug in a basic class like this would be found and fixed. So i think that cause of errors is me doing something wrong. Where is my error?

Comment: Python 3.3 has changed the string storage model, so it's possible that it used to work—or maybe that it used to work in narrow-strings builds.